# Close responsive menu after click on menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have this custom js code for basic (open/close) menu movement that was great when I used it on multi page websites, but it only closes the menu when you click the menu symbol. Now I need to implement it into a one page website and **I need it to close after a user clicks on a menu item**. I have very little experience in javascript so I need help solving this problem.

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = '#nav', no = 'nav-open';
    $('#nav-menu').click(function() {
        if ($(n).hasClass(no)) {
            $(n).animate({height:0},300);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(n).removeClass(no).removeAttr('style');
            },320);
        }
        else {
            var newH = $(n).css('height','auto').height();
            $(n).height(0).animate({height:newH},300);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(n).addClass(no).removeAttr('style');
            },320);
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="nav-hold">
  <div class="nav-bar"> 
    <a href="#one" class="nav-logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    <a href="#one" class="nav-logo-text">Company name</a>
    <a id="nav-menu" class="nav-menu-symbol">&#9776;<!-- menu symbol --></a>
    <a class="nav-menu">Menu</a>
    <ul class="nav-list" id="nav">
      <li><a href="#one">Top</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#five">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$('#nav-menu').click(function() {
```

if you want that your menu close only by clicking on the li element

```
$('#nav li').click(function() {
```

or if you want to close menu with both li and menu icon

```
$('#nav-menu, #nav li').click(function() {
```

Comment: Than you so much!  =]
You helped me a lot.
I used `$('#nav-menu, #nav a').click(function() {` and it worked perfectly!

Comment: can you please help me to fix it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552712/angular-4-mega-menu-is-not-closed-after-clicked-on-a-menu-inside-it @Vanojx1

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only bind the click function to the menu symbol. I'm not sure why you separate the symbol and text, but I would prefer to wrap it in single element. Also you can use jQuery `slideToggle()` to slide down or up on click. Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav-menu').click(function() {
      $('#nav').slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-hold">
  <div class="nav-bar"> 
    <a href="#one" class="nav-logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
    <a href="#one" class="nav-logo-text">Company name</a>
    <a id="nav-menu" class="nav-menu-symbol">
      <span>&#9776;</span>
      <span>Menu</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav-list" id="nav">
      <li><a href="#one">Top</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#five">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I will consider your recommendation.
Initially I intended the text to be hidden on the mobile version and to show with the symbol on the tablet version.