# How to close the hamburger menu when any menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to close the menu box when I click the menu item.

There is an input field when it's checked some style run and when it's unchecked the styles disappear.
The item menu's link created by react router(single page application)

I cannot use jquery.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import logoNoFrame from '../Assets/img/logo_noFrame.svg'

const Header = ({
  menuItems,
}) => {
  return (
    <header >
      <div className="logoAnimated">
        <Link to="/"><img src={logoNoFrame} alt="Logo" /></Link>
      </div>
```

start menu for max-width: 700px;

```
<ul className="menu">
  {menuItems.map(item => {
    return item.isActive && <li key={item.id}>
      <Link to={item.menuAddress}>
        <i className={item.menuClasses}></i>
        <span style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>{item.menuTitle}</span>
      </Link>
    </li>
  })}
</ul>
```

start hamburger menu for min-width: 700px;

```
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
<label className="toggle-container" htmlFor="toggle">
  <span className="button button-toggle"></span>
</label>
<nav className="nav">
  {menuItems.map(item => {
    return item.isActive &&
      <Link
        key={item.id}
        className="nav-item"
        to={item.menuAddress}
      >
        {item.menuTitle}
    </Link>
  })}
</nav>
```

end hamburger menu for min-width: 700px;

```
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**CSS style**

```
.menu {
  flex-basis: 35%;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 470px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #ff6c2f;
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu li:active > a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.menu a:before,
.menu a::after {
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 0;
}

.menu a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.menu a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu li:active > a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.menu a:hover::before,
.menu :active a::before,
.menu a:hover::after,
.menu :active a::after {
  width: 100%;
}
/* Menu Item animations */

@-webkit-keyframes itemMenu {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes itemMenu {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.menu li {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: itemMenu;
  animation-name: itemMenu;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.menu li:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

.menu li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 5.5s;
}

.menu li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.menu li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 6.5s;
}

.menu li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.menu li:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

/* responsive menu on max-width 600 */

.container-nav {
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px auto 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 534px;
  background-color: #533557;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Toggle functionality */

#toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  top: -100%;
}

#toggle:focus~.toggle-container .button-toggle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 285px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 285px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a, 0 0 0 8px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a;
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(1);
}

#toggle:checked~.toggle-container .button-toggle:after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
}

#toggle:checked:focus~.toggle-container .button-toggle {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 285px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a, 0 0 0 8px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: translate(-50px, 50px);
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item {
  color: #EC7263;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: 0.5s, opacity 0.1s;   
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item :hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(1):before {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(2):before {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(3):before {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:nth-child(4):before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

#toggle:checked~.nav .nav-item:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle:checked~.dummy-content {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#toggle:checked~.dummy-content:before {
  background-color: #0000004d;
}

.button-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: 0.6s;
  right: 16px;
  top: 9px;
}

.button-toggle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #0000001a, inset 0 0 0 20px #0000001a;
}

.button-toggle:before,
.button-toggle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #EC7263;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button-toggle:before {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg) scale(0);
}

.button-toggle:after {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
}

.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: itemMenu 1s 5s forwards;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: -6.2px;
  height: 7px;
  line-height: 7px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: scaleY(0.2);
  transition: 0.5s, opacity 1s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(1):before {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(2):before {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(3):before {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(4):before {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(1) {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(2) {
  letter-spacing: -7px;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(n+4) {
  letter-spacing: -8px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.nav-item:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #EC7263;
  transform: translateY(-50%) scaleY(5);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. How close is your question to this one about closing responsive menus? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434251/close-responsive-menu-after-click-on-menu-item If your question is not covered by this one can you edit your question to make it more specific? Another thing that will help you get a high quality answer is to trim your question down to be very specific about what you are asking. See How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info on asking a good question:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer. I set onClick on label tag to run closeMenu function. I also set checkInput into state and fixed in with change input :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import logoNoFrame from '../Assets/img/logo_noFrame.svg'

class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menuItems: {},
    checkInput: false,
  }

  closeMenu = () => {
    const checkInput = this.state.checkInput
    this.setState (prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        checkInput: !checkInput
      }
    })
  }

  render(){
    const { menuItems } = this.props

    return (
      <header>
        <div className="logoAnimated">
          <Link to="/">
            <img src={logoNoFrame} alt="Logo" />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <ul className="menu">
          {menuItems.map(item => {
            return item.isActive && 
              <li key={item.id}>
                <Link to={item.menuAddress}>
                  <i className={item.menuClasses}></i>
                  <span style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}> 
                     {item.menuTitle}
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </li>
            }
          )}
        </ul>
        <input
          id="toggle"
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.state.checkInput}
        />
        <label 
          className="toggle-container"
          onClick={this.closeMenu}
        >
          <span className="button button-toggle"></span>
        </label>
        <nav className="nav">
          {menuItems.map(item => {
            return item.isActive &&
              <Link
                key={item.id}
                className="nav-item"
                to={item.menuAddress}
                onClick={this.closeMenu}
              >
                {item.menuTitle}
              </Link>
          })}
        </nav>
      </header>
    );
  }
};

export default Header;
```